# Reusing Python flask code across multiple different sites

Tags: python, flask

I have a setup where I will have having around 50 sites using the same code, configured slightly differently. Rather than deploy the same code over and over again, duplicated across different folders and repositories, is there any way in Flask to centralise the working code of the site, as some sort of library?

In Django they have something a bit like this:

`https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/`

**Some ideas**

1. Deploy 50 instances of UWSGI, duplicating the same code and different config
2. Deploy 50 instances of UWSGI, with the python code added as a sort of module or extension so there is only one instance of the code: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/extensiondev/
3. Deploy 1 instance of UWSGI which has only one instance of the code and handles different hostnames: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/

The code that I am duplicating is designed to query an API and show the results. The differences between the sites are two fold:

1. Templating - Although the sites will look similar, they will not be identical. They will have slightly different CSS and images.
2. The API query. Most of the smaller sites are for towns and cities. This means that the API request from these sites will be slightly modified so as to return results only in that area.

   - sitelondon.com might query the API for items only in London by default
   - sitehtml.com might query the API for items which have the "html" keyword by default

The focus on my end is performance for the user. I will be running these initially on a server with 2GB RAM which should be plenty.

Comment: This all depends on what you are actually doing. Are you storing data in a database which is shared or in different databases?

Comment: Same database, slightly different template, and slightly different config (to control how the application queries the API), but aside from that all the code is the same.

Comment: If that is the case Paolo below is correct. And 2GB is not a lot for 50+ uWSGI instances. Do it in code if there is only a couple of differences.

Comment: There is no "right way" to answer this question. It depends much on what the actual code that you're duplicating (just some utility functions or are the site's database schemas/templates all pretty much exactly the same) resources (are you deploying to one host or to multiple hosts) etc. There's just too many different variables here for one way to be right.

Comment: I tried to edit it to get a little more information, does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally for these types of scenarios the "behaves differently based on Host" logic is built in the application.

So the better solution is **#3** but my suggestion is to *not use app dispatch*.

Build the logic to get the configuration for the `hostname` directly in the main application (for example you can load the specialized configurations in a `@before_request` handler and use a single DB instance).
If you plan to use only one small server, as you said, this solution is light on resource.

50 different uWSGI instances with their own processes would fill your memory and start swapping easily.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will the performance of the application suffer because I am almost having to build the application on the fly based on the hostname?

Comment: Depends on the differences but you can easily implement caching mechanism to deal with that if it will be the case. :) Sure is it would be a lot worse using 50 uwsgi instances!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Paolo that #3 is your best option.

You could simplify it even more with URL rewriting in your web server. If you rewrite the URLs such that a query for `http://sitelondon.com/example` becomes `http://sitelondon.com/london/example`, and a query for `http://sitehtml.com/example` becomes `http://sitehtml.com/html/example` then you can easily get the site through the routes:

```
@app.route('/<site>/example')
def example(site):
    return render_template(site + '/example.html')
```

With this setup you can organize your templates in sub-folders based on the site name, and then selecting the proper template becomes a matter of building the template path.

I hope this helps!